# Java error when removing element from list of (list of integers)

Tags: java, list, iterator

I got error when removing one of the element in my list of (list of integers).
I use iterator to remove that element

Here is my code:

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
....
....
Iterator<List<Integer>> myListIterator = list.iterator();
int ct1 = 0;
while (myListIterator.hasNext()) {
    List<Integer> val = myListIterator.next(); // here is the error 
    if(ct1 == val.get(0))
        list.remove(val);
    ct1++;
}
```

And I got this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you removed an element while using the iterator. A possible solution is, use a loop with index, and you can safely remove the element. You can also remove using **myListIterator.remove();**

Comment: so should I use for loop instead?

Comment: It should work.

Comment: Yes it works, thank you!